# Are Keystroke and Click Loggers Legal?

Tags: firewalls, legal, keyloggers

I worked with the firewall "Nobero" which is paid and bit expensive.

It is a complete Network Firewall including groups policy, banning URLs and social sites.

**But It has a feature of tracking users' keystrokes and mouse clicks (which is captured by the desktop client of the same firewall)**

It captures all the keys including everything if he/she uses facebook, gmail, or other personal sites. It captures everything and an administrator can see them.

***My question is whether it is legal to capture keystrokes and mouse clicks without notifying the user***

Comment: I assume this is a corporate network?

Comment: If the user has given informed consent, or if the user is in a workplace where it is considered acceptable and made clear in the work contract that users' actions are monitored indiscriminately *and* the company's system administrators have given informed consent, it is probably legal. Else it probably isn't. Depends on the local laws regarding data protection, the right to privacy in workplaces, contract law, computer security law, etc... Consult a (good) lawyer.

Comment: There is no legal Contract or there is no information Provided to user/employee that there actions are tracking .... I am From India and i dint found any good information about this law or vioalation

Comment: @amccormack yeah it is Corporate Network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Legal" means that it depends on the jurisdiction, so you will get at least one answer per country, and in some cases (e.g. federal states like the USA) many distinct answers for a single country.

*Usually*, in a business context, employees have a right, and an expectation, of privacy, meaning that spying upon their activities is not legal; employers cannot read emails, listen to phone calls, or, indeed, log keystrokes without knowledge and consent of the employees. However, in many jurisdictions, corporations can edict security policies that users must explicitly agree to when they sign their employment contract, and these policies may allow the employer to do some spying. This does not, however, entitle the system administrator to *use* the data which was thus grabbed.

Of course, even if made "legal" through user explicit consent, generic spying and grabbing of passwords and keys is a very efficient way to make employees very unhappy.

Comment: Question is bit Clear Now and Answer is NO, Employers cannot Spy without Legal Contract or without noticing user/employee.

Comment: Someone From India, Who know About this and law against this Violation, Please Come with us and Discuss it.